# merging data from two files to make a new data set

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file that contains a line with this script `(((A:__ ,B:__ ):__ ,C:__ ):__ ,D:__ )`

and I have six other text files with each containing 500 random numbers. I need to add those random numbers to the blanks in the first file.

I.e. If t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6 are the six files they have numbers such as

```
t1   t2   t3   t4   t5   t6
2    32   34   213  23   54
3    34   34   67   56   56 
5    45   78   78   89   32 
5    23   45   45   67   78
...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

After merging these together I should get a results like

```
(((A:2,B:32):34,C:213):23,D:54)
(((A:3,B:34):34,C:67):56,D:56)
```

etc.

I have tried paste function and loops to create this alignment but they don't put the text in the right spot. How do I make it work?
I am doing this in Linux.

Comment: Do you have to get the template from the first file, or can it just be hard-coded into the script?

Comment: I made the question nicely formatted. Why did you undo my work?

Comment: Yes the template should be the same as first file

Comment: I didn't undo it, Do I have to confirm you edit?

Comment: Hmmm... battling edits.

Comment: In the six files, the numbers are all on one line?

Comment: No, each of them are in separate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
paste t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 |
    awk 'BEGIN { getline < "template"; gsub("__", "%f"); format = $0 }
         { printf(format"\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6); }'
```

`paste` merges the 6 input files together. The first line of the `awk` script reads the first file (replace `template` with the filename) and changes each `__` to `%s`, so that it an be used as a format string with `printf`.

Comment: I tried this script. This results in  (((A:0,B:0):0,C:0):0,D:0)
(((A:0,B:0):0,C:0):0,D:0)
(((A:0,B:0):0,C:0):0,D:0)
So all the blanks are replaced by 0, Is format in your code a command or a file?

Comment: Some of these numbers are decimals, incase you need it

Comment: Actually I found it, I changed the "%d" to "%f" and it gives the way I wanted. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

A solution using bash file descriptors that worked for me...  I open a file descriptor for each text file (you have to start with FD 3, since 0-2 are taken by stdin, stdout, stderr.)  Then, as long as there is data in t1, I keep reading from t2-t6 and just print the output in the desired format.

```
#!/bin/bash    
exec 3<> t1.txt    
exec 4<> t2.txt    
exec 5<> t3.txt    
exec 6<> t4.txt    
exec 7<> t5.txt    
exec 8<> t6.txt    
while read one <&3     
  do    
    read two <&4    
    read three <&5    
    read four <&6    
    read five <&7    
    read six <&8    
    echo "(((A:$one,B:$two):$three,C:$four):$five,D:$six)"    
  done
```

Comment: I asked in the comments if the pattern could be hard-coded into the script, he said no, it has to come from the first file.